# SVG <use> resizing

Tags: svg

Hi I'm using reusable SVG components.

```
<svg id="svgs" style='display:none;'>
  <defs>
    <g id="cross" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
      <path d="M19.56....."/>
    </g>
  </defs>
</svg>

<div>
  The button
</div>
<button class='red-button'>
  <svg class='icon-cross' preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
   <use xlink:href="#cross"></use>
  </svg>
</button>

<div style='margin-top: 2em'>
  Small button :(
</div>
<button class='red-button small'>
  <svg class='icon-cross' preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <use xlink:href="#cross"></use>
  </svg>
</button>
```

See here on [codepen](http://codepen.io/teeerevor/pen/MKOQXe)

Is there a way to make the svgs respond to their container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *g* element doesn't have any supported *viewBox* attribute. If you change *g* that to *svg*, it will scale just fine. Like this:

```
<svg id="svgs" style='display:none;'>
  <defs>
    <svg id="cross" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
      <path d="M19.56....."/>
    </svg>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: AWESOME! svg-ception FTW. Thanks